# $\int\limits_0^\infty {x^4 \over (x^4-x^2+1)^4}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to calculate
$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(x^4-x^2+1)^4}dx$$

I have searched with keywords "\frac{x^4}{(x^4-x^2+1)^4}" and "x^4/(x^4-x^2+1)^4". But there are no results

Comment: The integral is same as$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4}(x^{2}+1)^{4}}{(x^{6}+1)^{4}}dx$$

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: I remember the days when people just did integrations rather than Google them.

Comment: These days are over!

Comment: Wolframalpha is better than google at integrating. So if you just want the answer, that's my go-to.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{3\pi}{16}.$

Comment: maple also can do it:$$ \int\frac{x^4}{(x^4-x^2+1)^4}dx={\frac {1}{ \left( {x}^{4}-{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{3}} \left( {\frac {77\,
{x}^{11}}{432}}-{\frac {59\,{x}^{9}}{144}}+{\frac {317\,{x}^{7}}{432}}
-{\frac {277\,{x}^{5}}{432}}+{\frac {67\,{x}^{3}}{144}}-{\frac {85\,x
}{432}} \right) }-{\frac {\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( {x}^{2}-\sqrt {3}x+1
 \right) }{648}}+3/16\,\arctan \left( 2\,x-\sqrt {3} \right) +{\frac {
\sqrt {3}\ln  \left( {x}^{2}+\sqrt {3}x+1 \right) }{648}}+3/16\,
\arctan \left( 2\,x+\sqrt {3} \right) 
$$

Comment: *That's* MAPLE's answer????  My goodness... the true answer is a simple $3 \pi/16$.

Comment: Note that in $0$ and $\infty$ the rational and logarithmic contribution is zero. Remains only the $\arctan$ value.

Answer (score 8):

For $b > 0$, define $I_b(a)$ by

$$ I_b(a)
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a}}{((x - x^{-1})^2 + 1)^b} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a+2b}}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^b} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

This integral converges if $|a+1| < 2b$. We can also prove that $I_b(a) = I_b(-a-2)$ holds, by using the substitution $x \mapsto 1/x$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= I_4(-4)
 = I_4(2) \\
&= I_4(2) - I_4(0) + I_4(-2) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((x - x^{-1})^2 + 1)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

So, by the [*Glasser's master theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem),

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(u^2 + 1)^3} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^4\theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \tag{$(u=\tan\theta)$} \\
&= \frac{3\pi}{16}
 \approx 0.58904862254808623221 \cdots.
\end{align*}

Comment: +1. I knew there'd be a Glasser solution somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to get to the same point as what @Sangchul Lee gives.

Let
$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, dx.$$
Then
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{x^4}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, dx.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto 1/x$ in the right most integral leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1 + x^6)}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1 + x^2)(x^4 - x^2 + 1)}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^4} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{x^4 (1 + x^2)}{(x^4 - x^2 + 1)^3} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1 + 1/x^2}{\left [\left (x - \frac{1}{x} \right )^2 + 1 \right ]^3} \, dx.
\end{align}
On setting $-u = x - 1/x$, $-du = (1 + 1/x^2) \, dx$ one has
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{(u^2 + 1)^3}\\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^4 \theta \, d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left (\frac{1}{2} \cos 2\theta + \frac{1}{8} \cos 4\theta + \frac{3}{8} \right ) \, d\theta\\
&= \frac{3\pi}{16},
\end{align}
as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Letting $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x} $ transforms the integral into
$$
I= \int_0^ {\infty} \frac{x^4}{\left(x^4-x^2+1\right)^4} d x =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{10}}{\left(x^4-x^2+1\right)^4} d x
$$
Averaging them gives
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^4\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^4-x^2+1\right)^3} d x= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-1\right)^3} d x=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left[\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+1\right]^3}
\end{equation}
Putting $\tan \theta=x-\frac{1}{x}$ yields
$$
\boxed{\int_0^ {\infty} \frac{x^4}{\left(x^4-x^2+1\right)^4} d x  =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^4 \theta d \theta=\frac{3 \pi}{16} }
$$